# Variable not being interpreted properly within quotations

Tags: node.js, variables, quotes, double-quotes, onesignal

```
  let adminIDs = _.map(Cause.admins, 'id');
  let message = {
    app_id: '**************',
    contents: {"en": "Yeah Buddy, Rolling Like a Big Shot!"},
    filters: [{"field": "tag", "key": "userId", "relation": "=", "value": adminIDs}]
  };
```

The response is the following:

```
{ id: '',
  recipients: 0,
  errors: [ 'All included players are not subscribed' ] }

console.log(adminIDs); returns an ID value
```

In the response it seems like the "adminIDs" in the filter, are not being read in from the variable "adminIDs" above. Is there something I need to do within the filters to have it read the variable properly? Thanks!

Comment: What does a console log of `message` show?

Comment: `{ id: '',
  recipients: 0,
  errors: [ 'All included players are not subscribed' ] }`

Comment: AdminID is responding!